# My MacBook Pro is crashing with kernel panic. What would be the reason?

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

My Macbook Pro is crashing with the Kernel Panics recently. I have sent the crash report to Apple with the following data. Can anyone analyse, what would be the issue for crashes ? I am on OS X El Capitan an Late 2011 15" with a new logic board replaced by Apple last year.

```
Sat Mar 19 18:14:04 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff8007a4ce64): assertion failed: inp->inp_flowhash != 0, file: /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.30.4/bsd/netinet/tcp_output.c, line: 1841
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8111f5b8f0 : 0xffffff80076df792 
0xffffff8111f5b970 : 0xffffff8007a4ce64 
0xffffff8111f5bbc0 : 0xffffff8007a5b72f 
0xffffff8111f5bc20 : 0xffffff8007bf27bc 
0xffffff8111f5bd90 : 0xffffff8007c053e8 
0xffffff8111f5be90 : 0xffffff8007c01fea 
0xffffff8111f5bf60 : 0xffffff8007c2a731 
0xffffff8111f5bfb0 : 0xffffff80077f0a36 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Safari

Mac OS version:
15D21

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: DECC9F02-27D7-31F0-9599-A9EF2873902C
Kernel slide:     0x0000000007400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8007600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8007500000
System model name: MacBookPro8,2 (Mac-94245A3940C91C80)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 39674020058308
last loaded kext at 36616281718277: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f8b195000, size 12288)
last unloaded kext at 37671783911187: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 900.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f8b195000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
com.astrill.macproxy.kext   2.0.9
com.paragon-software.filesystems.ntfs   187.1.14
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.20.22
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.51.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.51.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.4.0
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000    1.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   10.0.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller    1.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.12.6
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.12
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.51.3
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    205.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.4.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.6
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.12.6
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517.20.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 5.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B2C, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.4 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.69f3
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6770M, AMD Radeon HD 6770M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D534F344758334D314131333333433920
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D534F344758334D314131333333433920
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.3f4 16616, 3 services, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK7559GSXF, 750.16 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: iPhone
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete astrill from your MBP.
See if the panics stop.

com.astrill.macproxy.kext   2.0.9

Comment: I deleted Astrill, but the issue still persists. Looks like that the GPU is failing again.